# How can i remove columns from a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How remove columns from a table. Textbox values for removing columns numbers. 
Please refer this link for more info: 
 Javascript:

```
$("#target").click(function () {
    var removecolunms = $("#textval").val();
    $('table colgroup').find('col:eq("' + removecolunms + '")').remove();
    $('table tr').find('th:eq("' + removecolunms + '")').remove();
    $('table tr').find('td:eq("' + removecolunms + '")').remove();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sankars/zz3cH/346/)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Your text says "how many columns" you want to remove but you use :eq() selector, which actually is an iteration not an amount. Just a sidenote

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table').find('tr').each(function() {
    this.removeChild(this.cells[ 0 ]);
});
```

where `0` is columnindex

Answer (score 0):

You will have to iterate through each row of the table and remove the corresponding td and th element.

```
$('tr').each(function(){
    $(this).find('td:nth-child(' + colIndex + ')').remove();
    $(this).find('th:nth-child(' + colIndex + ')').remove();
});
```

Check out [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/divyanthj/0kq7wf97/4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <table border="1" style="width:100%" class="dataupdate">
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1 Col1</td>
        <td>Row 1 Col2</td>
        <td>Row 1 Col3</td>
        <td>Row 1 Col4</td>
        <td>Row 1 Col5</td>
        <td>Row 1 Col6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2 Col1</td>
        <td>Row 2 Col2</td>
        <td>Row 2 Col3</td>
        <td>Row 2 Col4</td>
        <td>Row 2 Col5</td>
        <td>Row 2 Col6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 3 Col1</td>
        <td>Row 3 Col2</td>
        <td>Row 3 Col3</td>
        <td>Row 3 Col4</td>
        <td>Row 3 Col5</td>
        <td>Row 3 Col6</td>
    </tr>   
    </table> 
    <form>
          <input type="text" id="numrow" placeholder="Row" >
          <input type="text" id="numcol" placeholder="Column">
          <input  type="button" id="removeButton" value="Remove" >  
    </form>
```

javascript

```
  $('#removeButton').click(
  function(){
   var numrow = $('#numrow').val();
   var numcol = $('#numcol').val();  
$('.dataupdate tr:nth-child('+numrow+') td:nth-child('+numcol+')').remove()
  });
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yy7qmedt/1/